# Basic React - Simple To Do App - Event Handling User Input - onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have a simple To do app that takes user input through a prompt and adds it to a list. I want to change the prompt and replace it with a text input bar. I've been having trouble implenting onChange and I'm hitting a wall trying to figure this out. I really appreciate the help as a beginner trying to learn.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
let id = 0
const Todo = props => ( 
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" checked={props.todo.checked} onChange={props.onToggle} />
    <button onClick = {props.onDelete}> delete</button>
    <span>{props.todo.text}</span> 
  </li>
)

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      todos: [], 
    }
    
  }
    addTodo() {
      const text = prompt("TODO TEXT PLEASE!")
      this.setState({
        todos: [...this.state.todos, {id: id++, text: text, checked: false},
        ]
      })
    }
    removeTodo(id) {
      this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id )

      })
    }
    toggleTodo(id) {
      this.setState({
        todos: this.state.todos.map(todo => {
          if (todo.id !== id) return todo
          return {
            id: todo.id,
            text: todo.text,
            checked: !todo.checked,
          }
        })

      })
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <div> Todo Count: {this.state.todos.length}</div>
      <div> Unchecked Count: {this.state.todos.filter(todo => !todo.checked).length} </div>
      <div className="App">
      <label> Task Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="task" 
      /* onChange={(e)=> { 
        setTaskName(e.target.value);*/ 
       />
      <button onClick={() => this.addTodo()}> Add ToDo </button>
   
      </div>

        <ul>
          {this.state.todos.map(todo => (
             <Todo
             onToggle={() => this.toggleTodo(todo.id)}
              onDelete={() => this.removeTodo(todo.id)}
              todo={todo}    
              />
              ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }     
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue you are having, you will need to also add a local state to store your input field data (you could get this with a [Controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) or [Uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) approaches):

```
this.state = {
  currentTodo: "",
  todos: [], 
}
```

And then in your input `onChange` event as you already did (you were using a hook based approach though), you could add a state update for your `currentTodo` value as you write. And also the current state value in the `input` tag (as [Cesare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13478993/cesare-polonara) observed):

```
<input type="text" id="task"
  value={this.state.currentTodo}
  onChange={(e)=> { 
    this.setState({ ...this.state, currentTodo: e.target.value});
  }
/>
```

Finally, to obtain the wroten text you can get it in your `addTodo` method.

```
   const text = this.state.currentTodo;
```

Comment: If you want to make it a controlled input you need to set the value on the input element.